# Uploading multiple images to server. If only one image is bigger than size limit or wrong file extension then all other fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-uploading

I have the following code that uploads multiple images to server. It works well as long as all the selected images are less than the size limit and of the correct file extensions. However if one image only doesn't fulfill those criteria then all other images fail to be published. Why? I want only the image that doesn't fulfill the criteria to fail.

```
    protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (UploadImages.HasFiles)
        {
            string strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            con.Open();
            try
            {

                foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in this.UploadImages.PostedFiles)
                {
                    string FileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(UploadImages.FileName);
                    if (FileExtension == ".jpg" || FileExtension == ".jpeg" || FileExtension == ".gif" || FileExtension == ".tiff")
                    {
                        UploadStatusLabel.Text = "";

                        int fileSize = UploadImages.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                        if (fileSize < 150000)
                        {

                            UploadStatusLabel.Text = ""; 
                            string newname = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd-hhmmss-") + uploadedFile.FileName;
                            uploadedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Images/Editors/BG/"), newname));
                            listofuploadedfiles.Text += string.Format("<br />Uploaded successfuly <img width='100px' src='/Images/Editors/BG/{0}'/>{0}<br clear='all'/>", newname );


                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO BackgroundImages(BG_fileName, IDuser) VALUES(@param1,@param2)";

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", newname);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            UploadStatusLabel.Text = "<strong>" + uploadedFile.FileName + "</strong> NOT uploaded. Size exceeds 150 kb limit. ";

                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        UploadStatusLabel.Text = "<strong>" + uploadedFile.FileName + "</strong> NOT uploaded. Wrong image format. Only jpg, jpeg, gif and tiff images are accepted. ";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error while inserting record on table..." + ex.Message + "Insert Records");
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();

            }



    }
        else
        {
            UploadStatusLabel.Text = "You Haven't selected a file to upload.";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work only on the specific item/file within your loop.

So, 
this: string FileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(UploadImages.FileName);
Should be: string FileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(uploadedFile.FileName);

And,
this: int fileSize = UploadImages.PostedFile.ContentLength;
Should be: int fileSize = uploadedFile.PostedFile.ContentLength;

You are getting the fileSize from the UploadImages instead of the specific file currently in the loop, which is uploadedFile.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `try-catch` inside the `for` loop, so that when an exception is thrown, it will be caught inside the loop, which can then just continue on. But be sure to keep your connection-closing code outside the loop.

The reason you're having that problem now is that when an exception is thrown (from inside the loop), it doesn't get caught until the `catch`, which is outside the loop.